# Take the average of nlargest columns ignoring the non-numeric columns

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any function to find out first '**n**' largest numbers and take an average of those two into a different column in pandas.

Note: Time or any non-numeric column to be ignored.

| `time` | n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 | average_largest_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11:50 | 1 | 2 | `3` | `4` | 3.5 |
| 12:50 | 5 | 6 | `7` | `8` | 7.5 |
| 13:50 | `8` | `7` | 6 | 5 | 7.5 |

Use this code if need be:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time = ['11:50', '12:50', '13:50']
data_1 = {'time': time,
          'n1': [1, 5, 8],
          'n2': [2, 6 ,7],
          'n3': [3, 7 ,6],
          'n4': [4, 8, 5],
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data_1)
df1
```

**Expected Result:** Average_largest_2_column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nlargest` per row and get the mean:

```
df1['average_largest_2'] = (df1.select_dtypes('number')
                            .apply(lambda r: r.nlargest(2).mean(), axis=1)
                            )
```

Or using the underlying numpy array:

```
a = df1.select_dtypes('number').to_numpy()

df1['average_largest_2'] = np.sort(a)[:,-2:].mean(1)
```

Output:

```
    time  n1  n2  n3  n4  average_largest_2
0  11:50   1   2   3   4                3.5
1  12:50   5   6   7   8                7.5
2  13:50   8   7   6   5                7.5
```

Comment: lambda function seems intuitive. 

For a huge dataset, do you think lamda function method would be more faster than the numpy method that you have mentioned?

Comment: also can we skip specific columns while calculating the mean in this question?

Comment: The numpy approach will likely be faster, if you want to apply only on a given list of columns, use `df1[list_of_cols].apply/to_numpy()`

Comment: Does this work as intended? I want to skip average_largest_2 column.

`df1['average_largest_3'] = (df1[0:6].select_dtypes('number')
                            .apply(lambda r: r.nlargest(3).mean(), axis=1)
                            )`

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def top_two(ls):
    ls = sorted(ls)
    return ls[-2:]


time = ['11:50', '12:50', '13:50']
df = pd.DataFrame( {'time': time,
          'n1': [1, 5, 8],
          'n2': [2, 6 ,7],
          'n3': [3, 7 ,6],
          'n4': [4, 8, 5],
        })


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    avg = sum(top_two([row['n1'],row['n2'],row['n3'],row['n4']]))/2 
    df['avg'] = avg

print(df)
```